# How can I put an icon inside a TextInput in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am thinking of having something like this https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3941 where you have icon that you press to show password as plaintext, not as dots. However, I was unable to find any custom component that would help me.

I don't want to put too much time on such a minor feature, so I'm asking without having attempted anything yet: Is there a custom component I've missed? If not, is there a simple way to add children to TextInput? Or should I just have TextInput and Touchable side by side?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use combination of View, Icon and TextInput like so:

```
<View style={styles.searchSection}>
    <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="ios-search" size={20} color="#000"/>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="User Nickname"
        onChangeText={(searchString) => {this.setState({searchString})}}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    />
</View>
```

and use flex-direction for styling

```
searchSection: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
searchIcon: {
    padding: 10,
},
input: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#424242',
},
```

Icons were taken from "react-native-vector-icons"

Comment: This is the way to do it if you don't want to use a library. Side note: if you want the icon to "disappear" you'll have to pass a prop to know whether a search is active or not, and then toggle the icon's visibility based on that search prop.

Answer (score 52):

Basically you can’t put an icon inside of a textInput but you can fake it by wrapping it inside a view and setting up some simple styling rules.

Here's how it works:

- put both **Icon** and **TextInput** inside a **parent View**
- set **flexDirection** of the parent to **‘row’** which will align the
  children next to each other
- give **TextInput flex 1** so it takes the full width of the parent View
- give **parent View** a **borderBottomWidth** and push this border down with **paddingBottom** (this will make it appear like a regular textInput with a borderBottom)

  - (or you can add any other style depending on how you want it to look)

**Code:**

```js
<View style={styles.passwordContainer}>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.inputStyle}
      autoCorrect={false}
      secureTextEntry
      placeholder="Password"
      value={this.state.password}
      onChangeText={this.onPasswordEntry}
    />
  <Icon
    name='what_ever_icon_you_want'
    color='#000'
    size={14}
  />
</View>
```

**Style:**

```js
passwordContainer: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#000',
  paddingBottom: 10,
},
inputStyle: {
  flex: 1,
},
```

*(Note: the icon is underneath the TextInput so it appears on the far right, if it was above TextInput it would appear on the left.)*

Comment: That's great! One improvement is to add ```alignItems: 'center'``` to passwordContainer in order to vertically center input and icon

Answer (score 14):

In case is useful I share what I find a clean solution:

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(text) => onChange(text)}
    value={value}
  />
  <Icon style={styles.icon} name="your-icon" size={20} />
</View>
```

and then in your css

```
 inputContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    height: 50,
  },
  icon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 10,
  }
```

Comment: This is working with the use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons

thank you

Answer (score 12):

This is working for me in ReactNative 0.60.4

**View**

```
<View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
    <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/ico-email.png')} //Change your icon image here
        style={styles.ImageStyle}
    />

    <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        placeholder="Enter Your Name Here"
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    />
</View>
```

**Styles**

```
SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#000',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 10,
},
ImageStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

 <TextInput
      label="Password"
      secureTextEntry
      right={<TextInput.Icon name="eye" />}
    />
```

Comment: You can even add some functionality

right={<TextInput.Icon onPress={someFunction} name="eye" />

Answer (score 3):

You can use this module which is easy to use: https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects

Comment: It certainly looks right, but in the example and readme there seems to be no indication of icons being able to react to being pressed.

Comment: If you fork the project you could wrap the icon with '<TouchableHighlight />'

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your `TextInput` in `View`.

```html
<View>
  <TextInput/>
  <Icon/>
<View>
```

and dynamically calculate width, if you want add an icon,

```
iconWidth = 0.05*viewWidth 
textInputWidth = 0.95*viewWidth
```

otherwise `textInputwWidth = viewWidth`.

`View` and `TextInput` background color are both white. (Small hack)

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is an example code to show Image Icon in TextInput// 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.

import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use. 

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
          <Image
            //We are showing the Image from online
            source={{uri:'http://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/user.png',}}

            //You can also show the image from you project directory like below
            //source={require('./Images/user.png')}

            //Image Style
            style={styles.ImageStyle}
          />

          <TextInput
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            placeholder="Enter Your Name Here"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>
         <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
          <Image
            //We are showing the Image from online
            source={{uri:'http://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/phone.png',}}

            //You can also show the image from you project directory like below
            //source={require('./Images/phone.png')}

            //Image Style
            style={styles.ImageStyle}
          />

          <TextInput
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            placeholder="Enter Your Mobile No Here"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },

  SectionStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#000',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 10,
  },

  ImageStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 5,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/-image-inside-textinput-example?session_id=snack-session-5bs1FKKUo)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who's struggling on this

you can try to follow mine also

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
     <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'row',paddingBottom:5, borderColor:'#ccc',borderBottomWidth:1}}>
             <TextInput 
                  style={{flex:1}}
                  onChangeText={(UserEmail) => setUserEmail(userEmail)}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor="#ccc"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  keyboardType="default"
                  returnKeyType="next"
                  ref={passwordInputRef}
                  onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
                  blurOnSubmit={false}
                />
                <FontAwesome5 name={"eye"} size={25} style={{alignSelf:'center'}}/>
   </View>
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are Willing to ADD Your OWN Custome SVG to the Left of Right.

Follow this..

```
Import svgs from "your Svgs Location"

    <TextInputRNP
       label="lable"
        placeholder="placeholder"
        right={<TextInput.Icon icon={() => <svgs.Calender />} size={30} />}
        left={<TextInput.Icon icon={() => <svgs.Calender2 />} size={30} />}
     />
```

Here **TextInputRNP** is the text Input from **React-native-Paper**

Comment: .i'm using svg it's enabled to press on but no color . it's just transparent ??

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example I took from my own project, i have just removed what i thought we didnt need for the example.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._makeYourEffectHere = this._makeYourEffectHere.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        showPassword: false,
        image: '../statics/showingPassImage.png'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this._makeYourEffectHere}>
          <Text>button</Text>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={require(this.state.image)}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TextInput password={this.state.showPassword} style={styles.input} value="abc" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _makeYourEffectHere() {
    var png = this.state.showPassword ? '../statics/showingPassImage.png' : '../statics/hidingPassImage.png';
    this.setState({showPassword: !this.state.showPassword, image: png});
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.94,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
    marginTop: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.03,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.012
  },
  image: {
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 7,
    bottom: 7
  },
  input: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.94,
    height: 30
  }
});

module.exports = YourComponent;
```

I hope It helps you.

Let me know if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something more specific like that based on Anthony Artemiew's response:

```
<View style={globalStyles.searchSection}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={globalStyles.input}
                        placeholder="Rechercher"
                        onChangeText={(searchString) => 
                       {this.setState({searchString})}}
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    />
                     <Ionicons onPress={()=>console.log('Recherche en cours...')} style={globalStyles.searchIcon} name="ios-search" size={30} color="#1764A5"/>

 </View>
```

Style:

```
 searchSection: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius:50,
        marginLeft:35,
        width:340,
        height:40,
        margin:25
    },
    searchIcon: {
        padding: 10,
    },
    input: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        marginLeft:10,
        borderTopLeftRadius:50,
        borderBottomLeftRadius:50,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#424242',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this too, dont forget to add the style below as well.

```
<View style={styles.searchContainerStyle}>
  <Ionicons name="search" size={24} color="gray"/>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TextInput
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search for doctors & labs"
      style={{ marginLeft: Sizes.fixPadding}} 
    />
  </View>
</View>

searchContainerStyle: {
backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
borderRadius: 30.0,
height: 45.0,
flexDirection: "row",
alignItems: "center",
paddingLeft: Sizes.fixPadding + 5.0,
marginBottom: 10,
},
```

Answer (score -1):

It's now more easier to use with [nativebase](https://nativebase.io/) input hope this will help someone. I used [Iconscout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iconscout/react-native-unicons) and you can use any icon library.

```
  <View style={styles.input}>
     <Input leftElement={<UilReact size="30" color="#61DAFB" style={styles.icon}/>} style={styles.input} size={'2xl'} variant="underlined" placeholder="Round" />
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   
    input: {
        justifyContent:'center'
    },
    icon: {
        marginRight:10
    }
});
```