# Put icon in placeholder - React Native

Tags: javascript, search, react-native, autocomplete

I'm using the npm react-native-autocomplete-input and my question is, how can I put the icon into the placeholder because there is no documentation about that.

I can't use another npm autocompletion because I have already coded some things.

For now, I have this :

[image]

The structure of the autocompletion is this :

```
<Autocomplete
    data={data}
    defaultValue={query}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}

    placeholder="Here is my placeholder"

    renderItem={data => (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: data })}>
          <Text>{data}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
)} />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put an icon inside a TextInput in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935381/how-can-i-put-an-icon-inside-a-textinput-in-react-native)

Comment: Nope, not the same because it's in the Autocomplete library, even if it's using TextInput, it's doesn't work as same. I've tried it with no success

Answer (score 1):

The library uses default TextInput, so there is no defined way to add placeholder image. you have to use a combnation if view adn autocomplete to make the layout.

```
<View style={styles.searchSection}>
    <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="ios-search" size={20} color="#000"/>
    <Autocomplete
    data={data}
    defaultValue={query}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}

    placeholder="Here is my placeholder"

    renderItem={data => (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: data })}>
          <Text>{data}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
)} />
</View>
```

Comment: Yeah, I will try this, but I think I will got the same result. Anyway, thanks you

Comment: @Erased u can give borderWidth & borderColor to View with flexDirection:row and inside u can give the icon and textinput .. the result will be better than this

Comment: I will try yes. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i solved it by using `bottom`, `left` and `position:absolute` to freely move the icon.

```
<View style={styles.container}>

       <FontAwesome name="search" size={20} color="#21344B" 
        style={{position:"absolute",bottom:20,left:15,zIndex:15,}}
        />

       <Autocomplete
          //Your Normal props
        />

</View>
```