# Having an icon in an TextInput in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to have an icon inside my TextInput in react native. This is my custom input I created. How can I have an icon in the left corner inside my TextInput?

```
import React from "react";
import { TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const defaultInput = props => (
  <TextInput
    {...props}
    style={[
      styles.input,
      props.style,
      !props.valid && props.touched ? props.invalidInput : null
    ]}
  />
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: "#eee",
    padding: 5,
    marginTop: 8,
    marginBottom: 8
  }
});

export default defaultInput;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put an icon inside a TextInput in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935381/how-can-i-put-an-icon-inside-a-textinput-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3):

If you need this only in android platform you can easily use [inlineImageLeft](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#inlineimageleft) prop of TextInput in react-native.