# How can I set an icon within a text input?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set an icon inside a text input.
I know, [there is this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935381/how-can-i-put-an-icon-inside-a-textinput-in-react-native).

But it is not working as expected since the icon is outside of the `TextInput`, I need it to be inside.

This is what I am obtaining so far:
[image]

This is my code:

```
         <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
            <Ionicons
              style={styles.IconWithinInput}
              name="ios-search"
              size={24}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.AddEditInputs}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
          </View>
```

And the styles:

```
  AddEditInputs: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },

  IconWithinInput: {
    padding: 10,
  },

  InputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

I made the input borders like a rectangle to show you better what I meant to say.

The last design will be like this:
[image]

And as you may see, the input border is at the bottom of the icon too.

What else do I need to achieve what I need?

Comment: You can't put the icon inside of the text input. The question that you linked as the answer, look at the answer with 11 upvotes. That actually explains better what you should do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46468835/1172189

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly put `icon` on the `textInput`. What you can do is wrap the `icon` and `textInput` with the view with `flexDirection` set to `row` and provide the `left padding` to the `icon` so that it seems to appear as in `textInput`. If you want to do so you can use something like this

```
 <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
     }}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <View style={{justifyContent: "center", marginRight: 5 }}>
        <Image
          source={{
             uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png',
              }}
              style={{ width: 10, height: 10 }}
            />
          </View>

          <TextInput placeholder="Enter your name" />
        </View>
      </View>
```

But my suggestion is to use the `Input component` of `react-native-elements` as it has `leftIcon` as `props`. You can find more information at [here](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Image
        source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
        style={{borderWidth: 1,width: 40, height: 40}}
        />
    <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        style={{borderWidth: 1, height: 40, borderColor: 'grey'}}
        />
         <View>
```

1. Wrap the component with flex and provide width for the icon. You can set the icon by having some wrapper around since it can not be included inside textbox.

Comment: Hi, try to add some comment about changes you made

Comment: @user1759586 code-only answers are considered as low quality, [edit] your answer and include short explanation why your code solves the issue