# Layout design Icon in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, layout

I have little experience in React Native. So that's why can anybody recommend me how to do this kind of screen? Just suggestion of what to use. I will do it by myself. I want to learn[image]

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask

https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43723780/9787887

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you have to install `react-native-vector-icons`, it needs link.

then If you use the third UI library, like the `react-native-eleemnt`, you can use it like this:

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon
  name='ios-american-football'
  type='ionicon'
  color='#517fa4'
/>
```

it has many icons. you can choose one type.

it also supports custom icon font. I use this [site](http://fontello.com/) to get font resources that are used to create a font. then you can use the following code to create a custom icon.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createIconSet,createIconSetFromFontello} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
const CustomFontConfig =  require('../Config/CustomFontConfig.json');
const iconSet = createIconSetFromFontello(CustomFontConfig,'fontello');

export default iconSet;
```