# How can I add an Material UI Icon to an input component in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got a basic input component in React and want to be able to add an Material UI - Icon either on the left or on the right side inside of the input field.

[image: like this]

What is the best practice for doing this?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You probaly looking for "input adornments"

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#input-adornments

```
<TextField
    {...textFieldProps}
    onClick={() => {}}
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
                <YourCustomIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
    }}
/>
```

Comment: I think this only works with a Material TextField, I want to use a normal <input>

Comment: I thought you using Material UI components; if yes: it's easier to use textField. if no: (i wouldn't add the Tag "material-ui") you have to use your own solution. (like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022113/placing-an-icon-inside-a-text-input-in-react-component)