# How to use inlineImageLeft in an Expo React Native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I was going through the React Native docs on `<TextInput />`

I saw a property called 'inlineImageLeft' and it seemed to add an icon on the left side of the `<TextInput />`.

But in the docs, its specified that the icon should be stored in `/android/app/src/main/res/drawable`

But I am using an Expo generated project. Is it possible to use this property on Expo?

Here is the example I tried from the react-native docs but it didn't work:

```js
<TextInput
    placeholder={`Search for ${currentMode}`}
    style={styles.input}
    value={searchState.search}
    onChangeText={handleChange}
    placeholderTextColor='white'
    autoCorrect={false}
    inlineImageLeft='search_icon' // Does not work
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the managed workflow (which it sounds like you are) then it is not possible to use `inlineImageLeft`. Even if you were in the bare workflow, this only works for Android.

You will have to build your own component that renders an icon/image inside the text input. Something like this: [How can I put an icon inside a TextInput in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935381/how-can-i-put-an-icon-inside-a-textinput-in-react-native)